# Understanding references to members in a struct within a struct, as well as how to dynamically allocate memory for struct members

Tags: c, struct, reference, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've looked at a few different questions with regards to the problem I am facing and while I feel like I've gained some insight I definitely have questions that I could use help with, so I wanted to solve a problem and get some help with the issues I'm facing in solving it.

I have an employee registry, I want to create a structure "Employee" that contains the data fields that I need for each employee. Within those fields I want another structure for their "Date of Birth" which has 3 ints within the struct - referring to month/date/year of birth. (See below)

```
typedef struct DOB {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
} Birthdate;

typedef struct EmployeeInfo {
    int empID;
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    Birthdate date;
    double salary;
} Employee;
```

Now I want my program to output a menu of choices and prompt the user for input that could lead to several options those being:

- Insert a new employee
- Update/change info about an employee
- Search for a specific employee
- Display all information about all employees

```
int main() {
  //create the array of Items
  Employee * employeeRecord = (Employee * ) malloc(N * sizeof(Employee));
  Birthdate * birthRecord = (Birthdate * ) malloc(N * sizeof(Birthdate));
  int empID;
  double salary;
  Employee Employee;
  Birthdate Birthdate;
  char opt;
  while (1) {
    dispayMenu();
    printf("Enter your Choice: ");
    scanf(" %c",&opt);
    switch(opt) {
        case 'i':
            printf("\nEnter empID: ");
            scanf("%d", & Employee.empID);
            printf("Enter firstName: ");
            scanf("%s", Employee.firstName);
            printf("Enter lastName: ");
            scanf("%s", & Employee.lastName);
            printf("Enter Date of Birth (month/day/year format): ");
            scanf("%d-%d-%d", &Employee.date.month,&Employee.date.day,&Employee.date.year);
            printf("Enter Employee salary: ");
            scanf("%lf", & Employee.salary);
            insertItem(employeeRecord, Employee);
            break;
        case 'u':
            printf("\nEnter empID to update: ");
            scanf("%d", & empID);
            updateItem(employeeRecord, empID);
            break;
        case 's':
            printf("\nEnter empID to search: ");
            scanf("%d", &empID);
            searchItem(employeeRecord, empID);
            break;
        case 'd':
            printData(employeeRecord);
            break;
        case 'q':
            quit(employeeRecord);
            break;
        default:
            printf("%c is not a valid choice", opt);
    }
  }
}
```

The first question I have is - how can I dynamically update the size of the array that contains all the employees? I get a segmentation fault currently; I don't want to globally create the size of the array; but I know I only need to update it when I have to add an Employee to the registry - so when I call the insert function - but I don't know how to keep a count for a variable in main that updates when insert is called.

The second question is in regards to changing the date of birth - I know I have to use -> operator somewhere so that I can access the fields within the second structure, but when I use it currently it tells me that the type is mismatched - its an int but expects type char*. So how do I access data within the structures to change from the update() function.

```
void updateItem(Employee * employeeRecord, int empID) {
  int i;
  char chng;
  for (i = 0; i < current_size; i++)
  {
      if (employeeRecord[i].empID == empID)
      {
          printf("What data do you wish to update?: ");
          scanf(" %c", &chng);
          switch (chng)
          {
          case '1':
              printf("\nEnter new First Name: ");
              scanf("%s", &Employee.firstName);
              break;
          case '2':
              printf("\nEnter new Last Name: ");
              scanf("%s", &Employee.lastName);
              break;
          case '3':
              printf("\nEnter new Date of Birth: ");
              // scanf("%d", &empID);
              // searchItem(employeeRecord, empID);
              break;
          case '4':
              printf("\nEnter new salary: ") break;
          case '5':
              printf("\nReturning to main menu.");
              break;
          default:
              printf("%c is not valid, try it again.", opt);
          }
      }
    break;
  }
  else{
  printf("Employee Not Found");
}
}
```

I've described it above, but essentially can't seem to reference the items within a struct correct and am having trouble correctly calling functions from main - says the implicit declaration doesn't match the type of the function, but that might have to do with errors within those functions themselves.

Comment: Please share a  [mre] instead of partial snippets.  For instance what is N? You already embed the Birthdate in the Employee so why do you wan to separately allocate a Birthdate?  The way you do it is fine, the other option is to make date a pointer.

Comment: Function should be declared before being called. So either move the function definition before main, or write a forward declaration AKA prototype for the runction and put that before the first call. I personally dislike unnecessary repetition, so I recommend just putting the function in source file before it gets called (so `main` is always the last function in the source file)

Comment: @hyde op it providing us with snippets so they may be doing this already without showing us.

Comment: @AllanWind read the last paragraph

Comment: @hyde missed the 3rd unnumbered question.  I will update answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. You store your Employees in a dynamically allocated array, then use `realloc()` to resize the array:

```
void insertItem(Enployee **employees, size_t *n, Employee e) {
   Employee *tmp = realloc((n+1) * sizeof(Employee));
   if (!tmp) {
      // fail
   }
   *employees = tmp;
   memcpy(*employees + *n, e, sizeof(Employee));
   (*n)++;
}

int main(void) {
// ...
   Employee *employees = NULL;
   size_t n = 0;
// ...
   case 'i': {
      Employee *e = malloc(sizeof(Employee));
      scanf("%d", e->empID);
// ...
      insertItem(&employees, &n, e);
   }
// ...
}
```

As `employees` and `n` belong together it would make sense to create a struct to hold them.

2. Within the `Employee` struct `Birthdate date` is also a struct.  You use `.` to access members of a struct via a value, and -> if you have a pointer.  In `updateItem()` you pass in an `Employee *employeeRecord` and use it as an array so you you either do:

```
employeeRecord[i].date.month = ...
// or
(employeeRecord + i)->date.month = ...
```

3. You can only reference functions already declared so you want `main()` last.  The other good option is to add declarations for your functions at the top.

Comment: Using `realloc` for single item insertions is _very_ inefficient. Better use exponential buffer allocation strategy.

Comment: @hyde Yes.  Op is clearly learning so I don't think it's a good idea to introduce that complexity now.  It's a toy problem so performance doesn't matter.   With snippets I did not write up all the missing code to test it, so I would also want to keep it as simple as possible to illustrate the solution even if it's not ideal.  Exponential buffer allocation also have issues; you may not want a 2x factor when you have a lot of data.  You may want 10x for small data.